# In a game, $0.38$ buy hotdogs, how large an order should she place if she wants to have no more that a 20% chance of demand exceeding supply?.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

A sell-out crowd of 42,200 is expected at Cleveland's Jacobs Field for next Tuesday's game with the Baltimore Orioles, the last before a long road trip. The ballpark's records from games played either in the season, she knows that, on the average, 38% of all those in attendance will buy a hot dog. How large an order should she place if she wants to have no more that a 20% chance of demand exceeding supply?.

**Attempt:**

Let $X$ = amount of order. Here X is a binomial distribution with $p = 0.38$ and $n = 42,200$.

Then

$P(X > x) = 0.20$  $\rightarrow$ $P(X \leq x) = 0.80$.

Then from the continuity correction we have

$P(X \leq x)$ = $P(\frac{(x - np)}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \leq \frac{(X - 42,200(0.38))}{\sqrt{42,200(0.38)(1-0.38)}}) = 0.80$

Then putting $P( z \leq \frac{(x - 42,200(0.38))}{\sqrt{42,200(0.38)(1-0.38)}}) = P(z  \leq \frac{x - 16036}{99.7111}) = 0.80$

I know I have to use the standard normal table to determine where $\frac{x - 16036}{99.7111}$ is about the standard normal table, then solve for $x$. But I don't know how to continue. Can anyone please help? Any feedback/help can help.
Thank you.

Comment: It seems to me unrealistic to assume that each fan passing through the entrance gate is a Bernouilli trial with probability $0.38$ of buying a hot dog. Some fans are very loyal, come to almost every game, and either do or don't eat hot dogs depending on whether they like hot dogs (not modeling an independent random variable on each day). Alternatively, most of the variation in hot dog consumption could be due to weather, which sharpens or dulls the appetite, or even how long the game is. But if we are told the distribution is close to binomial, then it's fine to use it.

Comment: @DavidK:  If you're a hammer, everything looks like a nail.  If you're in a probability class, everything looks like a distribution you know, even if it is foolish in the real world.  If they know $38\%$ buy hot dogs, maybe they know the dstribution as well.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, I expect either the phrasing here simply omitted the mention of the distribution, or it was strongly implied by context (e.g., previous examples using a binomial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, define a normalized variable
$$
Z={X-\mu\over \sigma}
$$
Then, on [the normal distribution table](http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~lzhou/stat302/standardnormaltable.pdf), you need to look for a probability equal to about 0.8. The linked table gives $z_0\approx0.84$ so we have
$$
P(Z<0.84)\approx0.80
$$
Thus to get the right number of hotdogs,
$$
{x_0-16036\over100}=z_0=0.84
$$
so
$$
x=16036+84=16120
$$